# mysql query result

Tags: mysql, join

I have built this query that is kind of self explanatory:

```
SELECT events.*,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM events_participants 
WHERE events_participants.eventid=events.eventid)AS participants,linkViews.totViews 
FROM events INNER JOIN linkViews ON events.event_id=LinkViews.eventid
```

In the events table i have 6 events but this query return just 3 of them (ID:1,2,4).

[image]

Where is this query wrong?

Comment: It's probably a issue with your join. Try a LEFT join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. Probably there is no matching eventid in the LinkViews table/view.